# Using tabs within tabs with

Tags: jquery, tabs

Well, here we go. I'm trying to make a list using techniques tabs, mounting css was perfeitoa, as well as the buttons for each category, the problem is that I am not able to make the call each content via jquery, for example:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#menu_tabs li a:first').addClass('active');
            $('#menu_rating li a:first').addClass('active');

            $('#menu_tabs li a').click(function(){
                $('#menu_tabs li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });                                              

            $('#menu_rating li a').click(function(){
                $('#menu_rating li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What I need:

This #manu_tabs is the top menu, the categories are, look page link

http://www.brasileiromx.com.br/web/classificacao_limpo.php

I managed to make the buttons stay active and inactive, can not do any more content to come when I click the mundial button by example.

The #menu_rating are the categories of each modality in the case MX1 and MX2, and these are within each parent category.

Use the link that went to see the HTML.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a very big page man. Would you create your tab on a jsFiddle and then share it with us?

Comment: Ok Hanlet Escaño, thank you for help. That's a share link jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2GfxL/

Comment: Thanks for the code. More people will look at it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I could do:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#menu_tabs li a:first').addClass('active');
            $('#menu_rating li a:first').addClass('active');

            $('#menu_tabs li a').click(function(){
                $('#menu_tabs li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                $(".tabs div").hide();
                $($(this).attr("href")).show();
                $($(this).attr("href")).find("div").removeClass("active");
                $($(this).attr("href")).find("div:first").addClass("active");
                $($(this).attr("href")).find("div:first").show();

            });                                              

            $('#menu_rating li a').click(function(){
                $('#menu_rating li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
               $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("div").hide();
                $($(this).attr("href")).show();
            });
        });
```

As you can see, the child tabs will not become active when you click the parent tab because they all share the same ID. I would suggest you remove duplicate IDs and style them with class names instead of by their ID.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GfxL/1/

Comment: Ow Hanlet, was good, very good. In case you are referring to $ ('# menu_rating li a: first'). AddClass ('active');
This is asking you to put classes with different names?

Thank you for now.

Comment: Sorry Hanlet, I did not understand where I have to change ID's repeated.

Comment: Your Ul elements have the titulo-categorias id.

Comment: OK! Good. More on jquery code I put in the click event?  http://jsfiddle.net/2GfxL/1/

Comment: I would like to thank very first Stack Overflow for giving this space for questions, problems and codes help.
Secondly the Hanlet Escaño, a person who all the patience in the world to help me in code, with his help I could understand how the FACILITY of jquery and the DOM manipulation.
I fried my head all afternoon and made ​​it to the final result. Http://goo.gl/0yowI can see here.

The code in jsFiddle here ready http://jsfiddle.net/2GfxL/1/ You'll be missing images, more are working perfectly.

Thanks again Hanlet Escaño, without you I would never have done it!

Comment: You don't have to thank me man. Here in SO we strive to help people. Please mark my answer as the solution if it helped answering your question. :) I looked at the page, it looks really good.